# 'Network Manager' does not detect any wifi network

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 16.10, intel-nuc

Using Intel NUC (NUC5CPYH) with Ubuntu 16.10, I am trying to configure my WiFi to connect it to my home wireless network.

However, when I start the 'Network Manager', it does not scan any of the wifi networks I can detect with my mobile phone. I am trying to bring up the wlan interface via terminal (with the 'Network Manager' closed), but I am not able to find which the name of the interface is. I expected it to be 'wlan0', but it seems not to be.

The output of 'lspci -knn | grep Net -A3' is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

The output of 'nmcli general status' is

```
STATE = disconnected
CONNECTIVITY = none
WIFI-HW = enabled
WIFI = enabled
WWAN-HW = enabled
WWAN = enabled
```

The output of 'nmcli device status' is

```
DEVICE = enp3s0 ; TYPE = ethernet ; STATE = unavailable ; CONNECTION = --
DEVICE = lo ; TYPE = loopback ; STATE = unmanaged ; CONNECTION = --
DEVICE = wlp2s0 ; TYPE = wifi ; STATE = unmanaged ; CONNECTION = --
```

Any similar experience? Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of 'nmcli general status' and 'nmcli device status'?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I've just included the output.